# MySQL Access Denied error from nodejs application running on port 4567

Tags: mysql, centos6, node.js

I can connect to a mysql database from the command line on centos 6.7:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP -p;
```

also:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost --protocol=TCP -p;
```

But if I connect from NodeBB running on port 4567 via an importer plugin I get an access denied error:

```
From a node application for importing data to the database I see:
22/11 09:11 [28144] - error: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/nodebb/node_modules/nodebb-plugin-import-punbb2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/var/www/nodebb/node_modules/nodebb-plugin-import-punbb2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:101:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/nodebb/node_modules/nodebb-plugin-import-punbb2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:270:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/nodebb/node_modules/nodebb-plugin-import-punbb2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/nodebb/node_modules/nodebb-plugin-import-punbb2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodebb/node_modules/nodebb-plugin-import-punbb2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:82:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

I have tried granting privileges on `*.* to 'root'@'%'` (this is a vagrant box) but the error persists.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this? I can connect to MySQL from a simple nodejs script on the same box without error using the same credentials.

SELinux is disabled:

```
sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#   enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#   permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#   disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#   targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#   strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: If you confirm my answer (providing it is correct) I would like to propose to change your question a bit so it's more generic to MySQL and any other application (for example, PHP(-FPM)/Python(Django)/(Ruby)Rails.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. As far as I can tell, though,  your answer has not resolved this so I would prefer not to change my question

Comment: @Joffrey I tried starting mysql in safe mode and it started working. ```sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables```. I think I may therefore have incorrect grants / privileges

Comment: How did you configure the passwords?

Comment: @Joffrey. The users and passwords were created as part of a puppet provisioning script which I did not write.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a default install of CentOS you should check your SELinux configuration. SELinux provides a fine grained access protection system to your system. This is controlled by the SELinux module in the kernel.

Any access controlled by SELinux will be logged (in a default install of CentOS) by the audit deamon. The log is located at `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and should have some entries specific to your MySQL access attempts.

By default on CentOS6 it is set to enforcing. This is configured in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`. After changing this a reboot is required.

You could disable SELinux but the most proper way is to add a policy to SELinux to allow MySQL access from a specific application. You can do this as explained in [the manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html).

Comment: This is a good suggestion and I had not considered it as I am not that familiar with CentOS. However, ```sestatus``` shows SELinux is disabled and I'm guessing that would have been the default for this particular Vagrant VM. There is nothing in audit.log relating to MySQL